# Implementing the Fibonacci sequence for the last n elements: The nBonacci sequence

Tags: python, iteration, fibonacci

I was curious about how I can implement the Fibonacci sequence for summing the last n elements instead of just the last 2. So I was thinking about implementing a function `nBonacci(n,m)` where n is the number of last elements we gotta sum, and m is the number of elements in this list.

The Fibonacci sequence starts with 2 ones, and each following element is the sum of the 2 previous numbers.

Let's make a generalization: The nBonacci sequence starts with n ones, and each following element is the sum of the previous n numbers.

I want to define the nBonacci function that takes the positive integer n and a positive integer m, with m>n, and returns a list with the first m elements of the nBonacci sequence corresponding to the value n.

For example, `nBonacci(3,8)` should return the list [1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31].

```
def fib(num):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while b <= num:
        prev_a = a
        a = b
        b = prev_a +b
```

The problem is that I don't know the number of times I gotta sum. Does anyone have an idea and a suggestion of resolution?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be m-n? The first n are 1 and the remaining m-n are obtained from the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nBonacci sequence will always have to start with `n` ones, or the sequence could never start. Therefore, we can just take advantage of the `range()` function and slice the existing list:

```
def nfib(n, m):
    lst = [1] * n
    for i in range(n, m):
        lst.append(sum(lst[i-n:i]))
    return lst


print(nfib(3, 8))  # => [1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to the fibonacci sequence recursively, you could do

```py
def fib(x, y, l):
    if len(l) == y:
        return l
    return fib(x, y, l + [sum(l[-x:])])


num = 3
print(fib(num, 8, [1 for _ in range(num)])) #[1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31]
```